# Looping issue making output repeat before I can quit the program

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I am writing a basic fast food ordering program and I am having trouble with either one of my loops or an error in returning one of my variables (so I think). My code runs but when I get to the end and i do not want to enter in another order, it asks me again and then displays the entire food menu, and after that output comes up it allows me to end the program. I will post half of code below where I believe the issue lies. I believe it has to also do with the userChoice variable.

```
  package lab08;

 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Lab08 {


 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String mealName[];
    double mealPrice[];
    mealName = new String[3];
    mealPrice = new double[3];

    LoadArraysFromFile(mealName, mealPrice);
    PerformTask(mealName, mealPrice);

}

//Load Arrays From File
  public static void LoadArraysFromFile(String mealName[], double 
       mealPrice[]) throws IOException {

    File mealInfoFile;
    Scanner mealFileSC;

    mealInfoFile = new File("mealInfoFile.txt");
    mealFileSC = new Scanner(mealInfoFile);
    int cnt = 0;
    while (mealFileSC.hasNext() && cnt < 3) {
        mealName[cnt] = mealFileSC.nextLine();
        mealPrice[cnt] = mealFileSC.nextDouble();
        mealFileSC.nextLine();

        cnt++;
    }
    mealFileSC.close();

}

  //Process Each Customer
   public static void PerformTask(String mealName[], double mealPrice[])
        throws IOException {

    char userChoice;
    userChoice = 'Z';
    while (userChoice != 'N') {
        userChoice = GetUserChoice();
        ProcessEachCustomer(mealName, mealPrice);
    }
}




//Get User Choice    
 public static char GetUserChoice() {
    char userChoice;

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Would you like to Order? (Y/N) ");
    userChoice = kbd.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    while (userChoice != 'Y' && userChoice != 'N') {

        System.out.print("Would you like to Order? (Y/N)");

        userChoice = kbd.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    }

    return userChoice;
}



    //Process Each Customer    
      public static void ProcessEachCustomer(String mealName[],
        double mealPrice[])throws IOException {

    int mealNumber;
    double[] mealTotals = new double[3];
    int[] quantities = new int[3];
    double[] totals;
    char userChoice;
     userChoice = 'Z';


    while (userChoice != 'N') {

        ProcessEachMeal(quantities, mealName, mealPrice);
        totals = UpdateMealTotals(mealPrice, mealTotals, quantities);
        DisplayOrderSummary(mealPrice, mealTotals, quantities, totals, 
         mealName);
         LogTransaction( mealPrice,  mealTotals,  quantities,  totals,  
         mealName);
        userChoice = GetUserChoice();


    }
}



     //Process Each Meal
      public static void ProcessEachMeal(int[] quantities, String 
       mealName[], double mealPrice[]) {
        int mealNumber;
      //loop

      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    DisplayMenu(mealName, mealPrice);
    mealNumber = GetMealNumber();
    UpdateQuantities(quantities, mealNumber);


     }
```

Comment: Have you considered prompting user "after" they've placed there order?  Otherwise you'll need an `if (userChoice != 'N') {...}` option inside the loop

Comment: what other way could i terminate my program without putting `break;`? under the `if (userChoice != 'N')`

Comment: The termination is fine, it’s when your asking it that’s the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to call `GetUserChoice()` once before starting `while-loop` and then after processing order.

```
public static void PerformTask(String mealName[], double mealPrice[]) throws IOException {
    char userChoice;
    // ask for first time
    userChoice = GetUserChoice();
    while (userChoice != 'N') {
        ProcessEachCustomer(mealName, mealPrice);
        // ask again so if user is done (userChoice='N') while-loop will terminate
        userChoice = GetUserChoice();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**: All the methods aren't present so I can't run the complete code but here is what you can do to avoid 2 times printing of question.

Below will ensure that you only ask for user choice when performing task and not when processing each customer.

```
// Process Each Customer
public static void PerformTask(String mealName[], double mealPrice[]) throws IOException {
    char userChoice;
    userChoice = GetUserChoice();
    while (userChoice != 'N') {
        ProcessEachCustomer(mealName, mealPrice);
        userChoice = GetUserChoice();
    }
}

// Get User Choice
public static char GetUserChoice() {
    char userChoice;
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Would you like to Order? (Y/N) ");
        userChoice = kbd.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    } while (userChoice != 'Y' && userChoice != 'N');
    return userChoice;
}

// Process Each Customer
public static void ProcessEachCustomer(String mealName[], double mealPrice[]) throws IOException {
    int mealNumber;
    double[] mealTotals = new double[3];
    int[] quantities = new int[3];
    double[] totals;
    ProcessEachMeal(quantities, mealName, mealPrice);
    totals = UpdateMealTotals(mealPrice, mealTotals, quantities);
    DisplayOrderSummary(mealPrice, mealTotals, quantities, totals, mealName);
    LogTransaction(mealPrice, mealTotals, quantities, totals, mealName);
}
```

Comment: I used your advised code and it does not re-loop through the entire program but it re-loops "Would you like to Order? (Y/N)" twice and then on the second time the program terminates.

Comment: that is because you are calling GetUserChoice() twice, once from PerformTask and other from ProcessEachCustomer. This means that you are asking user choice twice, once for performing task and once for processing each customer. You would need to align their logics so it will only ask once.

Comment: Thanks man for all the help the above code works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Matt - np, about your question on processing each customer, you can either add GetMealNumber() in processing customer or processing meal. Make sure you add just once and then ask for options just like above.

Appreciate if you can accept the answer, if it has helped you resolve your issue.